# How to read an excel file and extract the values of a column in an array

Tags: php, excel, symfony

I want to read an excel file and return an array contain the values of column A ,I am working on excisting project and they use LiuggioExcelBundle

what I found that their is a function that read from the excel file but I dont know how to itearate on column A and put the value in array and return it.

```
filename = $this->container->getParameter('xls_fixture_absolute_path');
    // load the factory
    /** @var \Liuggio\ExcelBundle\Factory $reader */
    $factory = $this->get('phpexcel');
    // create a reader
    /** @var \PHPExcel_Reader_IReader $reader */
    $reader = $factory->createReader('Excel5');
    // check that the file can be read
    $canread = $reader->canRead($filename);
    // check that an empty temporary file cannot be read
    $someFile = tempnam($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir'), "tmp");
    $cannotread = $reader->canRead($someFile);
    unlink($someFile);
    // load the excel file
    $phpExcelObject = $reader->load($filename);
    // read some data
    $sheet = $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet();
    $hello = $sheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();// instead of a value of 
    $world = $sheet->getCell('B2')->getValue();// A1 how to extract all 
                                               // A vlaues   

    return new Response($canread && !$cannotread ? "$hello $world" : 'I   should no be able to read this.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that (I did not test it):

```
$output=array();
foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cell = $sheet->getCell('A'.$row->getRowIndex())->getValue();
    $output[] = $cell;
}
var_dump($output);
```